# Mongoose - Selecting and Sending Virtuals from Populated Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a little trouble getting my mongoose virtuals to show up from deep populated fields. Here is the code of the backend function that is not behaving as I'd like it to:

```
exports.get_user_feed = async (req, res, next) => {
  const options = { sort: { date: -1 } };
  const user = await User.find(
    { username: req.params.user },
    "username posts avatar followers following"
  )
    .populate({
      path: "posts",
      options,
      populate: [
        {
          path: "author",
        },
        { path: "comments", populate: { path: "author" } },
      ],
    })
    .sort({ "posts.date": 1 });
  res.json({ ...user });
};
```

And here is the comment schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  targetPost: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: true },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  content: { type: String, maxlength: 400 },
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment" }],
  stars: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});

// Virtual for post's URL
CommentSchema.virtual("url").get(function () {
  return "/" + this.targetPost.url + this._id;
});

// Virtual for formatted date.
CommentSchema.virtual("formatted_date").get(function () {
  return (
    DateTime.fromJSDate(this.date).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_MED) +
    " at " +
    DateTime.fromJSDate(this.date).toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE)
  );
});

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema);
```

My goal is to get the comments from each post to also include the formatted_date of the comment, but this virtual is not getting included in the response that is sent - all the regular properties are being sent but not the virtual. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Commnet Schema file before module.exports.

```
CommentSchema.method('toJSON', function () {
  const {
    ...object 
  } = this.toObject({ virtuals:true });
  return object;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - I actually did figure this out on my own by adding this code to the CommentSchema:

CommentSchema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });